# No route matches [GET] "/"...Sometimes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I'm a bit of a Rails n00b, so I'll apologize if this is really simple.  When I access my server from another computer, I get this message:

> No route matches [GET] "/"

And if I try to go to my subpages (Well, currently I only have one), I get something along these lines:

> ## Unknown action
>
> The action 'index' could not be found for AwebpageController

But here's the catch: this only happens sometimes.  The rest of the time, the standard RoR homepage loads, and going to wwww.mydomain.com/awebpage serves up the page fine.

My Routes.rb looks like this:

```
Wobsite::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :awebpage
end
```

And awebpage_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class AwebpageController < ApplicationController
end
```

And yes, index.html.erb for Awebpage does exist.  It's all so simple that I don't understand what's going wrong.  Oh, and my webserver is Thin (Not sure if that matters).  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add this to the top of your routes file to set the default controller and page for your site (i.e. http://www.mysite.com/):

`root :to => "AwebpageController#index"`

To remove the default Ruby on Rails webpage you'll also want to delete the `index.html` file in your `/public/` directory.

Also, although not required, in your controller you're missing the function definition for index.

```
class AwebpageController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Normally you'd do application logic and serve up a view in this function; however if you do nothing RoR automatically loads the view associated with the page (index.html.erb).

If after all this you're still having a problem perhaps explicitly add `index` to the `AwebpageController` in your routes file; perhaps rails is only mapping `www.mysite.com/Awebpage/` to `Awebpage/index` and not `www.mysite.com/Awebpage/index`.

Comment: I read that if you don't even define it, Rails would do the same thing (i.e. load the view).  Was this wrong?  After all, it does work sometimes.  And anyway, that still doesn't address why I'm getting a routing error to the root of my site.

Comment: You are correct that the function definition and the explicate routing should not be required. If you've added the `root` declaration to your routes file and you're still having the problem the only thing I can think of is explicitly telling Rails what to do.